# Circular definition of a subset: is it admissible?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, definition

Consider a set of points $\mathcal{A}$. I want to define the subset $\mathcal{A}^*$ of $\mathcal{A}$ as the collection of elements of $\mathcal{A}$ such that, for every two pairs of such elements $a,a'$, it holds that
$$
f(a,a')=k \text{ implies } a=a'
$$

This is a circular definition, as observed in the comment below.

**1)** Is such a circular definition admissible?

**2)** If it is admissible, how do we define formally $\mathcal{A}^*$?

My attempt is
$$
\mathcal{A}^*\equiv \{a\in \mathcal{A}: \text{ }\forall a'\in \mathcal{A}^*,f(a,a')=k \text{ implies } a=a'\}
$$

Comment: But your verbal def **is** circular...

Comment: Yes exactly. Is that circularity wrongly posed? Can we have sets defined by circular arguments?

Comment: Do you mind if I ask what the context is for such a set? As written, the problem I see is that there may be several $\mathcal{A}^{*}$ types of subsets since you're just looking for collections with certain intrinsic properties. For example, if $\mathcal{A}=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and your "relation" was "any two elements sum to an even number", then you would have $\mathcal{A}_1^{*} = \{1,3\}$ or $\mathcal{A}_2^{*} = \{1,5\}$ or $\mathcal{A}_{3}^{*} = \{1,3,5\}$ or ...

Comment: @JoeDub $\mathcal{A}$ contains vectors of real numbers. You are indeed correct, in the sense that $\mathcal{A}^*$ "is not uniquely defined". I don't know how to convey that in the notation.

Comment: If you're not expecting $\mathcal{A}^{*}$ to be unique, then I don't think set-builder notation is the way to go (although I've not had my coffee yet, so maybe I'm overlooking something obvious). I would probably state it in words: "Let $\mathcal{A}^{*}$ be any subset of $\mathcal{A}$ for which the following is true: for all $a,a' \in \mathcal{A}^{*}$, if $f(a,a')=k$ then $a=a'$." That's not particularly useful on its own since many singletons probably satisfy this property, so you'll probably further want to take $\mathcal{A}^{*}$ to be maximal.

Comment: It might help (me, at least) if you made clear that $f$ is a function whose domain is $A\times A$ and $k$ is a particular value in the range of $f$ (if, indeed, that's what $f$ and $k$ are), so that your starting point is not just a set $A$ but a set $A$, a function $f$, and a value $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An arbitrary subset $S$ of $\mathcal{A}$ either does or doesn't have the property you seek for $\mathcal{A}^\ast$, namely that any $a,\,b\in S$ with $f(a,\,b)=k$ implies $a=b$. This property of $S$ defines a unique choice of $\mathcal{A}^\ast$ if, and only if, exactly one subset of $A$ has the desired property. This may be true or false depending on the choice of $\mathcal{A},\,f,\,k$. However, the empty set certainly does, so $\mathcal{A}$ is either undefined or the empty set.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that while $\mathcal{A}^*$ is not uniquely determined, the empty set is not the only sensible choice. One can also try to apply Zorn’s Lemma to get a maximal set with the desired property (still not necessarily unique, of course).

Comment: @EikeSchulte In other words, we'd use a further property to select among the candidates. One can, of course, always do that if the property provably selects something unique, but the choice of such a property is left to the OP.